# Why is the Point adding in steps of 1 when iterating the for in Scala?

Tags: arrays, scala

```
case class Point(x: Int, y: Int){   
  def +(rhs : Point) : Point = Point(x + rhs.x, y + rhs.y)    
}

object ArrayTest {    
  def main(args : Array[String]) : Unit = {    
    val a : Array[Point] = new Array(5)    
    val p : Point = Point(6, -4)    
    for(i <- a.indices) a(i) = p    
    for(i <- a.indices) a(i) += Point(2, i)    
    var sum = 0    
    for(p <- a) sum += p.y    
    print(sum)   
  }    
}`
```

a(i) gets updated like this:
(8,-4),
(8,-3),
(8,-2),
(8,-1),
(8,0)
but I don't understand why y is adding 1 through every iteration. I don't understand why in the second for loop as `a(i)` is added to the point, `p` increases its `y` by `1`, where is this happening?

Comment: Not sure to understand what's your question. In the second loop, `a(i)` is updated with a new value which is `a(i) + Point(2, i)`

Comment: Side note: you probably want to learn how to use a debugger and step through code step by step.

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer. I mean a(i) gets updated like this: (8,-4), (8,-3), (8,-2), (8,-1), (8,0) but I don't understand why y is adding 1 through every iteration

Comment: Because `i` iterates through the indices `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`. For `a(0)`, you're adding `Point(2, 0)`, so `Point(6, -4) + Point(2, 0)` gives `Point(8, -4)`. For the last index, you're adding `Point(2, 4)`, so `Point(6, -4) + Point(2, 4)` gives `Point(8, 0)`.